# With an identifier traverse through a JSON object and get a specific value with the identifier

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Traverse through a JSON object which has nested arrays objects inside it . 
The **label**  value is provided which is the identifier with which need to return the associated level **metrics** value . If the label is found in the 2nd level find the metrics at the second level and it should be returned

I couldn't get the logic on how to traverse through an object and return the specific value

```
function getMetrics(arr, label) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].label === label) {
      return arr[i].metricsValue;
    } else if (arr[i].children) {
      return getMetrics(arr[i].children, label);
    }
  }

  return "Not found";
}
const selectedMetrics = getMetrics(dataObj.series, '1');
```

Consider the JSON object with **children** specifies the sub level of the current level .

```
const dataObj = {
  series: [
    {
      label: "A",
      metricsValue: "ma",
      children: [
        {
          label: "A-B",
          value: 6,
          metricsValue: "ma-mb"
        },
        {
          label: "A-B-C",
          metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc",
          children: [
            {
              label : "A-B-C-D",
              value: 6,
              metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc-md"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "1",
      metricsValue: "m1",
    }
  ]
};
```

Expected Result :
When the input is "1", it should return

```
selectedMetrics= "m1"
```

Input : "A-B-C-D"

```
selectedMetrics= "ma-mb-mc-md"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a [Depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS) or [Breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) to find `metricValues` at any level.

Here I'm using DFS to find the required value. This works for data with any nested levels.

```js
const dataObj = { series: [ { label: "A", metricsValue: "ma", children: [ { label: "A-B", value: 6, metricsValue: "ma-mb" }, { label: "A-B-C", metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc", children: [ { label: "A-B-C-D", value: 6, metricsValue: "ma-mb-mc-md" } ] } ] }, { label: "1", metricsValue: "m1"} ] };

function getMetrics(arr, label) {
  var result;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].label === label) {
      return arr[i].metricsValue;
    } else if (arr[i].children) {
      result = getMetrics(arr[i].children, label);
      if (result) {
       return result;
      }
    }
  }

  return null;
}

console.log("selectedMetrics for 'A' = " + getMetrics(dataObj.series, 'A'));
console.log("selectedMetrics for 'A-B' = " + getMetrics(dataObj.series, 'A-B'));
console.log("selectedMetrics for 'A-B-C' = " + getMetrics(dataObj.series, 'A-B-C'));
console.log("selectedMetrics for 'A-B-C-D' = " + getMetrics(dataObj.series, 'A-B-C-D'));
console.log("selectedMetrics for '1' = " + getMetrics(dataObj.series, '1'));
```

Comment: That's a lot cleaner! Nice.

Comment: For input "1" it fails

Comment: @RenJith - Good catch! Fixed that. Let me know if it still isn't working for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e passing in the value, so use it instead of the string & you're not accessing the children nodes.

```
 for(var i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
        const x = arr[i];
        if (x.children.label === value) {
          console.log(x.metricValue)
        }else{
          x.forEach(element => {
            if (element.children.label === value) {
              console.log(element.metricValue)
            }else{
              element.forEach(secondEl =>{
                if (secondEl.children.label === value) {
                  console.log(secondEl.metricValue)
                }
              })
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

You can create a more elegant way of iterating around the children nodes but that may help you out